# How to make a list constructor to add data constructors (A list of account constructors)

Tags: haskell

I am fairly new to haskell and I am trying to add account constructors into a list and then check that list according to the account number and do certain modifications to them.
I know how to do this without lists, but I am not sure how to do it using list constructors. I am using a network simple server where the user enters the account number and I transfer it to the methods.

This is my talk server. (l) is "Open 1975". Where Open is to determine the definition to be used and 1975 is the account number.

```
talk :: Handle -> IO ()
 talk h = loop
  where loop = do
          l <- hGetLine h
          hPutStrLn h "Reply"
          let ws = words l
          case (head ws) of ("Open") -> open h ws
                            ("Tranfer") -> transfer h ws
```

Here are my constructors (I am not user about the list constructor)

```
data Account = Account
  { nameArian :: String
  , namePres :: String
  , accNum :: TVar Int
  , accValueA :: TVar Float
  , accValueP :: TVar Float
  }

createAccount nA nP acc valA valP cR = do
  valA' <- newTVar valA
  valP' <- newTVar valP
  return $ Account nA nP acc valA' valP'

data Lista = Lista { list :: TVar [Account]}

createList a = do
  a' <- newTVar a
  return $ Lista a'
```

This definition opens an account and adds it to the list

```
open :: Handle -> [String] -> IO ()
open h ws = do
  let num = read (unwords (tail ws)) :: Int
  accounts <- atomically . sequence $
    zipWith3 createAccount ["Arian"] ["Pres"] [x] [0.0] [0.0] [0]
  let accVar = accounts
  accls <- atomically . sequence $
    zipWith createList [accounts]
```

Sorry if it is a little bit messy.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If the way I am creating the list is useful or not, or should use standard list to add the accounts to it?

Comment: Okay. This isn't really the right forum for opinion-based questions like "is this a good way to do things". If your code is working the way you want it to, you could try the code review StackExchange instead, where that is exactly the kind of question they're looking for.